# Detect Changes on Word (API Office)

Tags: typescript, ms-word, office-js

When you're editing a Word Document, it automatically detect after any update on the file.

I don't find this feature in the Microsoft Documentation, Does it exist ?

Beause, I would like to show a popup (to quit) only if there are modifications.

Currently, i have to compare my two (base64 - string) documents, it seems to be not reliable, i prefere a event.

Thanks

More informations :
My code is based with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=office-js#getfileasync-filetype--options--callback- (getFile)

```
function _arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any *event* in the COM object model that detects when a Word document is being/has been edited.

There's a `Saved` property which can be queried to find out if changes have been made. This doesn't mean, however, that *no* changes have been made to the document. It only reports whether there are any changes that haven't yet been saved to disk (True = no change pending; False = changes present in memory that haven't yet been saved).

And there's a `DocumentBeforeSave` event that notifies when a `Save` command has been issued.

The Word JS API also has a `Document.Saved` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=office-js#saved

The Office JS APIs have an event `BindingDataChanged` that may help. Start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.eventtype?view=office-js and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.binding?view=office-js

If it's necessary to know whether any changes have been made, at all, then a comparison is necessary.

Comment: Hello ! Sorry for the delay, thanks a lot for the response. I'm using "insertFileFromBase64(...)" (Office Js) so, i don't think is possible to use a "save" event/property (i will/can not save it on the disk). My probleme is, i don't know why, my value (string base64) change whereas i don't even change the document (i'm using "getFile()", then make a copy on another variable. Just before my comparison, i get the whole document with the same method but it's never equal  (===) (length is different by example) I don't know if it's the cause of the encoding or getFile().

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e2fceea2-3c6a-414f-b3a2-276c10fa27ea/event-onchanges?forum=worddev
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184